# Inserir dados e "chave primária" no Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Bom dia,

Estou começando com programação, e estou com a seguinte dúvida.
1. Consigo inserir dados no firebase, porém, quando tento inserir novamente ocorre apenas a substituição dos dados em vez de inserir o novo registro.

2. Como consigo inserir dados no firebase junto com a "chave primária"?  (campo em destaque na imagem, é apenas para exibir o campo que desejo, não é o meu banco no firebase).

[image: Imagem de banco no firebase com o campo "chave primária"]
Abraços.

Answer (score -1):

Tente isso.

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
 mDatabase.child("tasks").push().setValue(firebaseData, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            //Problem with saving the data
            if (databaseError != null) {

            } else {
                //Data uploaded successfully on the server

               }

            }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Não entendi bem a sua pergunta mas vou tentar responder.

A chave primária pode ser informada por você ou pode ser gerada pelo Firebase.

Para inserir um registro informando a chave: **db.collection("users").doc("chave do meu usuario").set(objetoComInformacoesDoUsuario);**

Para inserir um registro sem informar a chave (chave é gerada pelo Firebase): **db.collection("users").doc().set(objetoComInformacoesDoUsuario);** Neste caso, o retorno desse método será um objeto contendo, entre outras coisas, a chave criada.

Para atualizar o registro você precisa da chave. Para obter a chave: **var referenciaDoUsuario = db.collection("users").doc("chave do meu usuario");**

Com isso em mãos, basta fazer **referenciaDoUsuario.update({ nome: "Nome do usuário" })**

Obs.: Não sei em qual plataforma você está desenvolvendo. Utilizei como base a web (Javascript).
Documentação: **https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data**